# What is the English word for "female philosopher"?

Tags: word-choice

Is there an English word to refer to a female philosopher rather than philosopher in general?

Comment: Why do you think we need separate words for philosophers based on their gender?

Comment: Women are writers, teachers, players, etc.... What's wrong with philosophers?

Comment: I'd call her a **philosophatrix**.  It's probably wrong, but the word **does** show up on internet search: https://www.google.com/search?q=philosophatrix&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8 with approximately the definition you're looking for.

Comment: what about Philo Sophia?

Comment: If you wanted to form a new word, the regular way would be by simply adding -ess: philosopheress. Compare to teacheress and manageress. the endings -tress or -trix are the feminine counterpart of the endings -ter or -tor.

Comment: Actually if you're going to use -ess, it's fairly conventional to drop at least the vowel preceding the r, so you'd say philosophress. Compare mister to mistress or doctor to Doctress, for examples. Also yes, Doctress was a word in the Webster's A.D.E.L. 1828 Though honestly, I prefer Philosophist from the same dictionary "One who loves/practices sophistry." which only makes legitimate sense if sophistry is considered as the practice of logic, rather than the lack of it. (How a word comes to be its own antonym and still be used in both ways, I'll never understand...)

Comment: I edited the question, trying to make it more consistent with the scope defined in help center. Please consider if close votes can be retracted. Thank you.

Comment: ............Shegel

Comment: @JasonStack Aw I'm a bit sad that you removed the original story from the question. I quite liked it.

Comment: @dwjohnston I had to :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A woman philosopher is a **philosopher**.

Philosopher is not a gendered term.

Dictionary.com:

> a person who offers views or theories on profound questions in ethics, metaphysics, logic, and other related fields.

If you're wanting to be a bit more poetic or creative you could use:

**Oracle** or **Pythia** which refers to any priestess at the Temple of Apollo, in ancient Greece.

[From the Wikipedia article:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythia)

> The Pythia (/ˈpɪθiə/,[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythia) Greek: Πυθία [pyːˈtʰi.a]), commonly known as
>   the Oracle of Delphi, was the name of any priestess throughout the
>   history of Temple of Apollo at Delphi, located on the slopes of Mount
>   Parnassus, beneath the Castalian Spring (the new priestess was
>   selected after the death of the current priestess). The Pythia was
>   widely credited for her prophecies inspired by Apollo.

It's worth noting that gendered terms are on their way out. [For example, woman actors are referring to themselves as ***actors*** now, not actresses.](http://www.theguardian.com/theobserver/2011/sep/25/readers-editor-actor-or-actress)

Comment: If you're going to stretch *philosopher* into *preistess*, *sybil* works, too.

Comment: `woman actors are referring to themselves as actors now, not actresses` Those would be *female* actors, eh? You wouldn't say "man actors". In any case, I'll believe it when the Academy stops giving separate actor/actress awards. (-:

Comment: Of course you wouldn't say "man" actor. Man is not the counterpart of female: You'd say male. That's somewhat common, albeit comparatively  to the traditional method. Also while I do agree that philosopher is neutered, maybe The Asker wants a gendered word to help specify this individual. I think that's something feminist politicians aren't considering enough: Gendered words highlight the accomplishments of women by reminding people that they're just as capable of holding the job. I do get that the job usually shouldn't be about gender and are useful for describing unspecified people though...

Comment: @Tonepoet What are the gendered words for 'male nurse', 'male teacher', 'male daycare provider', or 'male secretary'? Men are just as capable of holding those jobs and nobody seems to be concerned that we need to be reminded of that. It's not about *gendered* terms. It's about marked versus unmarked.

Comment: @Tonepoet  I don't get your first point - are you defending the answer's use of "woman actor"?

Comment: I misread Jim; take it as a reaffirmation of the point that female is preferable, although perhaps 'women' might've been acceptable in this context. Kit, I did mention that in my last statement but if I am not mistaken, all of those words are *already* neuter since long ago, even nurse which Webster was expressly inclusive with in his 1828 definition, at least in the context of tending to the sick (suckling is naturally different). I'd love to chat in more detail but this is a poor place for this type of discussion, esp. without anything relevant to say to this answer like my last comment.